# How to copy element of a row (of a column) and paste to row-1 (of another column) in csv, using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using pandas to make a csv file, with some of the columns have its data already. For example it looks like this

```
col1   col2
   1     2
   3     4
   5     6
   7     8
```

Let's call n - row location of the column,

if n=1, `n(col1) =1`, `n(col2) =2`

if n=2, `n(col1) =3`, `n(col2) =4`

etc.

Now I want to add col3 and col4 and it will looks like this

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
   1     2
   3     4
   5     6
   7     8
```

I want to write value of col1 when n=2 into col3 with `n(col3)=1`, and value of col2 when n=2 into col4 with `n(col4)=1`, and so on. It will looks like this

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
    1     2      3      4
    3     4      5      6  
    5     6      7      8
    7     8      9     10
```

I am writing a code in python which is incomplete

```
import pandas
result = pandas.read_csv('csvfile.csv')
n = 0
for n in range (0,25):
    a = result.loc[n, 'col1']
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), but last row values are missing:

```
df[['col3','col4']] = df[['col1','col2']].shift(-1)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2   3.0   4.0
1     3     4   5.0   6.0
2     5     6   7.0   8.0
3     7     8   NaN   NaN
```

If want replace them, e.g. by `0`:

```
df[['col3','col4']] = df[['col1','col2']].shift(-1, fill_value=0)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     3     4
1     3     4     5     6
2     5     6     7     8
3     7     8     0     0
```